# Hive: Split string using regexp as a separate column

Tags: sql, regex, split, hive, hiveql

I have a string in a text column. I want to extract the hashtag values from the string into a new table so that I can find the distinct count for each hashtag.

Example strings->

> NeverTrump is never more. They were crushed last night in Cleveland at
>   Rules Committee by a vote of 87-12. MAKE AMERICA GREAT AGAIN!
>
> CrookedHillary is outspending me by a combined 31 to 1 in Florida,
>   Ohio, & Pennsylvania. I haven't started yet!
>
> CrookedHillary is not qualified!
>
> MakeAmericaSafeAgain!#GOPConvention #RNCinCLE
>
> MakeAmericaGreatAgain #ImWithYou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am outlining the steps here as I'm not that good with the query, may update the answer once I get it right

1. Replace '#' in string by ' #'.
2. split each word in a string with space as delimiter.
3. use `explode()` lateral view functionality to get all the words of the string.
4. use a `WHERE` condition to fetch records starting with "#". `LIKE '#%'` condition should work.
5. then add the group by condition to get the counts of each hashtag.

Answer (score 2):

This is what @lazilyInitialised said, I did a query with your data example:

```
with your_data as (--This is your data example, use your table instead of this CTE
select stack( 1, 
1, --ID
"   NeverTrump is never more. They were crushed last night in Cleveland at Rules Committee by a vote of 87-12. MAKE AMERICA GREAT AGAIN!

    CrookedHillary is outspending me by a combined 31 to 1 in Florida, Ohio, & Pennsylvania. I haven't started yet!

    CrookedHillary is not qualified!

    MakeAmericaSafeAgain!#GOPConvention #RNCinCLE

    MakeAmericaGreatAgain #ImWithYou
"
) as (id, str)
)

select id, word as hashtag
from
(
select id, word
  from your_data d
       lateral view outer explode(split(regexp_replace(d.str, '#',' #' ),'\\s')) l as word --replace hash w space+hash, split and explode words
)s 
where word rlike '^#'      
;
```

Result:

```
OK
id      hashtag
1       #GOPConvention
1       #RNCinCLE
1       #ImWithYou
Time taken: 0.405 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```